# Removing action from function inside class wordpress returning false

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to remove a function from the `init` filter which is located inside a class, and tried based on what i have read.

wp-content/plugins/plugin_name/includes/class-wps-deals-public-pages.php

```
class Wps_Deals_Public_Pages {
   public function wps_deals_register() {
      // some content here
   }
   public function add_hooks() {
     add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'wps_deals_register' ), 100 );
   }
}
```

Main file of plugin wp-content/plugins/plugin_name/deals-engine.php

```
require_once( WPS_DEALS_DIR . '/includes/class-wps-deals-public-pages.php' );
$wps_deals_public = new Wps_Deals_Public_Pages();
$wps_deals_public->add_hooks(); // add_hooks is getting called here
```

wp-content/themes/my_theme/overriding_template_that_overrides_the_plugin_template/create_account.php

```
global $wps_deals_message, $wps_deals_public;
var_dump(remove_action( 'init', array( 'Wps_Deals_Public_Pages', 'wps_deals_register' ), 1000 ));
```

The `var_dump()` returns false instead of true, and tested and indeed is not removing the function from the hook, I also tried

```
var_dump(remove_action( 'init', array( $wps_deals_public, 'wps_deals_register' ), 1000 ));
```

`$wps_deals_public` => this is the object from the specified instantiated class `Wps_Deals_Public_Pages`.

Comment: Ok managed to figure it out, it was because of the priority and second worked well:

   `var_dump(remove_action( 'init', array( $wps_deals_public, 'wps_deals_register' ), 100 ));`

This one returns true, odd, if I replace `$wps_deals_public` with the class it returns false. But the issue is that it reuturn now true just that it doesn't remove it.from the hook, I get same messages, not getting the messages from the customized function.